# Python script for date comparison in excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am a beginner, please help me with the program logic to create a python script using pandas for the following.

I have a excel sheet with 5 columns and many rows containing the details of expiring ssl certs. **Fourth column has the date of expiry.**

I need to write a ***Python script to check date in each cell of 4th column and if the date is within 60 days time frame from today I need to copy the entire row to a new sheet***, like wise need to append all the rows which are in this time frame and mail this new spreadsheet.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open sheet `sheetname` from `excel_path` use

```
df = pd.read_excel(excel_path, sheetname=sheetname)
```

Consider the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   "b": [7,8,9,0,1,2],
                   "c": [3,4,5,6,7,8],
                   "date": ["2018-01-01", "2018-02-02", "2018-03-03",
                            "2018-04-04", "2018-05-05", "2018-06-06"]})
>   a   b   c   date
0   1   7   3   2018-01-01
1   2   8   4   2018-02-02
2   3   9   5   2018-03-03
3   4   0   6   2018-04-04
4   5   1   7   2018-05-05
5   6   2   8   2018-06-06
```

First, convert `date` column to `datetime` dtype with necessary [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Get differences between items in `df["date"]` and today and filter them:

```
days_threshold = 60
filtered_ix = (pd.Timestamp("now") - df["date"]).dt.days < days_threshold
```

Select filtered rows from dataframe using [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
filtered_df = df.loc[filtered_ix]
```

To save filtered rows to Excel on sheet `output_sheet` with filepath `output_path` use `df.to_excel`:

```
filtered_df.to_excel(output_path, sheet_name=output_sheet, index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this logic koPytok  I have constructed the program but I get this error. **AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'days'**

Comment: Show me the line with error

Comment: FilteredList=(pd.Timestamp("now")-df["ValidityEndDate"].dt.days < ExpiryLimit)

Comment: AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'days'

Comment: Remove last `) ` and add `) ` between `["ValidityEndDate"] ` and `.dt`: `["ValidityEndDate"]).dt`

Comment: Thanks KoPytok, it worked.

Comment: But one miss, i need to output only the rows withtin today -> 60days. It outputs all day from the start of the year until 60days from now.

Comment: Anyway I tried to apply 2 filters 'FilteredList=(df["ValidityEndDate"] > pd.Timestamp("now"))
df2=df.loc[FilteredList]
FilteredList=(df2["ValidityEndDate"]-pd.Timestamp("now")).dt.days < ExpiryLimit'  any other easy solution?